# Lombok with default value from config

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I have this Lombok class but the values are not injected when I create the class

```
@Data
@Builder
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Task  {


    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${timeInMinutes}")
    private @NotNull Integer timeInMinutes;
```

Comment: which Value annotation is this?

Comment: How are you creating that class? That annotation looks like a Spring annotation. Spring can only inject those values for beans it manages (i.e. if you call the constructor yourself from the code, it's an unmanaged bean and spring won't do anything)

Comment: @Chris this class has component annotation, so that's not problem. The problem is with  AllArgsConsructor

Answer (score 3):

If you would want to fetch the value from application properties, Use a custom constructor instead of using the annotation @AllArgsConstructor.

```
public class Task {


  private Integer timeInMinutes;

  Task(@Value("${timeInMinutes}") Integer timeInMinutes){
       this.timeInMinutes = timeInMinutes;
  }

}
```